# Keyboard shortcut for accessing address bar in Firefox

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on my Mac, but it doesn't take me to the address bar. Instead, the key seems to insert a random character. Is there an alternative shortcut?

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11573/chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-go-to-address-bar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> a.k.a. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> does the trick.