# Chrome: Keyboard shortcut to go to Address Bar?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

I just recently switched from Windows and *nix to OS X, and I miss being able to hit F6 to go straight to my Address Bar. What's the OS X equivalent?

Comment: see also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/keyboard-shortcut-for-accessing-address-bar-in-firefox

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To switch quickly to the Address Bar use:

- Mac/OS X:     <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Win/Linux:     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: IIRC cmd+L works also in Safari, Firefox and Opera; and ctrl+L does the same magic in Windows' versions of the browsers — though not in the same manner in IE: it opens up an `Open URL` dialog.

Comment: ⌘+L doesn't work for me in Chrome 61 for Mac/OS X. Only works in Firefox

Comment: How do you switch back to the main pane?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, by pressing a 'Tab' key

Answer (score 8):

### Catch and remap your keystroke in the browser.

Using Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100 64 bit on a MacOS Mojave 10.14.4.

**Chrome should tell you what your shortcut is under `File -> Open Location...`:**
[image]

Clearly the shortcut is command-L

### But you want to change that keystroke to be `Command-e`, like old times.

1. Open `System Preferences` -> `keyboard`
2. Go to `Shortcuts` tab -> `App Shortcuts`
3. Click the plus to add a new Application specific key remapping.
4. Choose Google Chrome.
5. Use the string: `Open Location...` case sensitive, include space and dots.
6. Use the hotkey detector and type `command-e`.
7. Click add and close to save.  Restart Chrome.  Press your new key.
8. The `File -> Open Location...` command should be executed.

**Visual:**

[image]

This remap appears to occur somewhere between how the Application negotiates the keymaps between itself and the operating system.

Comment: Works for me nicely with Cmd key, but not with Option (Alt) +something unfortunately.

Comment: My command+L stopped working somehow. Even if it is what it shows next "Open Location...". So I had to remap it to something else using this method, thank you.

Comment: Yes, using the Alt key is not working, which is unfortunate because the command on Windows, which I'm trying to match, is Alt+D.

Comment: Also, most of step 7 ("Click add and close to save. Restart Chrome. Press your new key") is unnecessary on Big Sur. The menu in Chrome shows the updated shortcut as soon as you click "add."

Comment: This worked great for me, I'd tried to get it working but was missing the ellipses at the end!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have mine setup.

I wanted <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to behave like <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> did in windows.  I had to re-associate the bookmark to another key as well as associating the Open Location... to <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

You must enter exactly as appears in menu so if its got 3 dots include this :

[image: Ventura 13.2]