# How I can unminimize windows from an application using a key combination?

Tags: macos, window-manager

Coming from the Windows world, I was initially used to using Cmd-Tab to switch between open windows. On OS X this switches between applications, so I had to learn to use Ctrl-` to switch between windows in an application. However, even this doesn't seem to switch to minimized windows and (for better or worse) I am in the habit of minimizing windows. The only way I have found to unminimize them is to long-click on the icon in the dock and select the window I want, which is annoying. Is there a key combination I can use which will switch between windows and unminimize them at the same time, or any related keys which would help?

I am using OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm from the same boat;

the best native keyboard-only  I've found is

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>DOWN-Arrow</kbd>; (you enter app expose)
2. <kbd>DOWN-arrow</kbd>; (if there are any minimized windows, this'll put a cursor on one)
3. <kbd>LEFT-arrow</kbd>/<kbd>RIGHT-arrow</kbd> (to select from multiple minimized windows) *or* hold OPT if you want all of them restored.
4. <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

---

alternative step1: getting into app expose before you've <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>'ed to an app:

with <kbd>CMD</kbd> still held down, (the task switcher is visible)
tap <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, or <kbd>UP</kbd>, or <kbd>1</kbd> (now in app expose)

---

The above shows only one app's minimized windows at a time; for selecting from any minimized window regardless of app, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> moves focus to the dock, and you can arrow left to get to the minimized list.

if your <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> instead shows you the app-expose, try <kbd>FN</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>. (In my settings/keyboard, I've flagged "Use all <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. keys as standard function keys")

---

Some apps have specific alternatives; I use Terminal's <kbd>CMD</kbd>-window_number, which unminimizes and focuses that window.

Comment: Using this technique one can easily follow the same path with gestures

Comment: nice find and summary

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at tip #10 on http://www.macworld.com/article/2048857/10-tips-for-managing-minimized-windows.html -- that did it for me.

Essentially, you use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>~</kbd> as usual, and for minimized windows, hold down the <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd> key before releasing the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key, and the application opens as you last minimized it.

Comment: This works, but seems very clumsy to me; I have to _know_ it was minimised (which isn't obvious from the Cmd-Tab window), and the keychord isn't exactly easy to manage either. Thanks though :)

Comment: I either can't get this to work on El Capitan, or can't follow what it's trying t say.

Comment: Works for me on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1. The idea of pressing `opt` before letting go of `cmd` seemed tricky to me before I realised there is another `opt` key on the right of the keyboard - I never use it!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to unminimize ALL windows (not just from one application), you can create the following Automator service and assign it a hot key.

In Automator, create **new service**

Give it one action: **Run Shell Script**

The shell script is this:

`killall -HUP Dock`

This will kill the Dock process (which will then respawn), in the process liberating all windows that have been minimized into the Dock.

[image]

Save the service, then use **System Preferences** to assign a shortcut key to the service.

Comment: I tried this manually in the terminal `killall -HUP Docker` and it did not work as described.  I'm running Mojave macOS 10.14.6.  It's been 7 years since this answer was posted, so maybe the OS behavior has changed since then.

Comment: "Docker" isn't the same as "Dock"

Comment: That said, it appears that restarting the Dock process indeed does not maximize minimized windows anymore. Alas.

Comment: Typing "killall Dock" in the terminal and pressing return un-minimized all of my windows in all open applications on macOS 12.7.1.

"killall -HUP Dock" did not do anything at all

Answer (score 1):

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) includes minimized windows by default. You can also assign shortcuts for showing only minimized windows and unminimizing windows.

[image]

You could also [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    try
        set miniaturized of windows to false -- most applications
    end try
    try
        set collapsed of windows to false -- at least Finder
    end try
end tell
```

If minimizing windows to application icons is not enabled, this clicks the icon for the last minimized window in the Dock:

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
        click (last UI element of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to work. Using Witch's default Window Cycle key includes minimized windows in the list, but doesn't actually unminimize them when you switch to them.