# Restore multiple minimized windows?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, window-manager

This question particularly deals with the latest version of Google Chrome on Mountain Lion, but the underlying premise applies to other browsers/applications as well.

What I am wondering is: is there a way (via keyboard shortcut, or third party application) to open a series of minimized windows simultaneously?

For example, in Google Chrome, one might have four windows open (each with a set of tabs), that you minimized with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. This leads to a few questions:

1. Once minimized, is there a keyboard shortcut to bring that window back?
2. Is there a keyboard shortcut that would bring *all minimized* windows back?

I would like to restore *all minimized windows* with a keypress, [not just one at a time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/keyboard-shortcut-for-restoring-applications-from-the-mac-os-x-dock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If minimizing windows to the application icon has not been enabled, you can unminimize all windows with a script like this:

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
        click (UI elements of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
    end tell
end try
```

This script would unminimize the last minimized window shown in the Dock:

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
        click (last UI element of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
    end tell
end try
```

This would unminimize all windows in the current application:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    if name is "Finder" then
        set collapsed of windows where collapsed is true to false
    else
        set miniaturized of windows where miniaturized is true to false
    end if
end tell
```

You can [assign shortcuts to scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) by for example using FastScripts or Alfred.

Comment: Alternative solution that doesn’t require third-party apps like Alfred: You can use Automator. Just create an “Application” called something like “Unminimize All Windows” and then just use Spotlight to summon the app every time you want to unminimize (as fast as hitting Cmd-Space, typing “Unminimize”, Enter). Note that creating a Service or Quick Action won’t work since every app in which you invoke the service would need to be separately granted special security privileges to run the AppleScript which is tedious and insecure

Answer (score 10):

The opposite keyboard shortcut for the cmd+M is the

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + Tab

that will bring up all open windows

keep holding the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key

scroll till you find lets say Chrome

still holding the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key use up down arrows that will bring all open windows with in that app.

THIS QUESTION WAS ANSWERED [HERE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/keyboard-shortcut-for-restoring-applications-from-the-mac-os-x-dock):

Actually there a multiple ways doing the minimizing and the maximizing all windows at once.

I prefer the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to hide all at once. Then <kbd>F3</kbd> to show all.

Then there is a [3 party app](http://manytricks.com/witch/) called Witch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I was actually hoping for a simple key combination that would restore all windows in the dock simultaneously - which is a bit different from the other thread.  The solution presented there is good for restoring one of the minimized windows (select it with up/down), but it leaves the other windows in the tray...

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly no one mentioned this method for restoring **all minimized windows from an application**.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl-Down</kbd> to show all windows from the current application.
2. Press <kbd>Down</kbd> to select a minimized window (doesn't matter which one).
3. To restore the selected window, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   To restore **all** windows, **hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key** and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Voilá! All minimized windows for that application are restored.

(For the curious: I accidentally hid all my Safari windows with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> when trying to create a comment in Google Docs. Thus my motivation to solve this...)