# Automatically maximize windows when cycle through them using cmd + tab

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, window-manager, bettertouchtool

I'm pretty new to macOS and today I tried to find out how to maximize a window as I cycle through them using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/keyboard-shortcut-for-restoring-applications-from-the-mac-os-x-dock) I found that I can maximize window just clicking <kbd>alt</kbd> before I release <kbd>cmd</kbd>.But I'd like to have Windows/Ubuntu like behaviour.

Is there any way to always hold <kbd>alt</kbd> key automatically so that any toggled window will be maximized? 
Is there any way to adjust so through standard macOS settings or through third party software, e.g. such as BetterTouchTool?

Comment: Do you actually mean maximise, or restore?

Comment: He wants "alt" to be pressed automatically when releasing the ⌘Tab shortcut, without having to press it himself

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not sure which word suits better, but here is the scenario: e.g. you work with chrome and then minimize it by cmd+M. I want to be able to switch back using just cmd+tab (not cmd+alt+tab)

Comment: Ah, OK. tbh it's a situation I simply avoid. I have 6 Spaces across 2 screens, so 12 'desktops' in all. I put specific apps in specific places & toggle between them using the Spaces shortcut keys. No minimising or Cmd/Tab required; I just go straight to the Space for the app I need.

Answer (score 0):

[AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) may help you here. It still ***not*** a solution for the native <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

But you will be able to replace it by setting the new shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.