# Keyboard shortcut for switching from address bar to main pane in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut

The question how to go from the main pane to the address bar is answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11573/chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-go-to-address-bar). 
But how do I move from the address bar, back to the main pane, without having to reload the page by pressing `Enter`, or by using `Tab` a bunch of times?
I'm on a mac, but the question is applicable for any OS, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/726447/keyboard-shortcut-to-deselect-omnibox-in-chrome), but the easiest solution is to make a [custom search engine](https://xavierchow.github.io/2016/03/07/vimium-leave-address-bar/) with the url as `javascript:`.

If you set the keyword to a letter (`l` for example), typing `l + return` will exit the address bar.